# Running rails 5.x in docker, error is Unable to load application: NameError: uninitialized constant Bundler rails_1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I am trying to get rails 5.x working using docker.

My Dockerfile is:

```
FROM ruby:2.5-alpine

RUN apk update && apk --update add \
 build-base \
 nodejs \
 postgresql-dev \
 tzdata \
 imagemagick

# yarn
ENV PATH=/root/.yarn/bin:$PATH
RUN apk add --virtual build-yarn curl && \
    touch ~/.bashrc && \
    curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | sh && \
    apk del build-yarn


RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY Gemfile ./
RUN gem install bundler -v 2.0.1
RUN bundle install --binstubs
```

My docker-compose file looks like:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"

services: 

  rails:
    build: ../../railsapp
    volumes:
     - ../../railsapp:/app     
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"    
    command: puma -C config/puma.rb
    env_file:
      - '.env'
    restart: always
```

The docker logs has this error:

> rails_1      | Puma starting in single mode... rails_1      | *
>   Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.3-p105), codename: Llamas in Pajamas rails_1 
>   | * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5 rails_1      | * Environment:
>   production rails_1      | ! Unable to load application: NameError:
>   uninitialized constant Bundler rails_1      |
>   /app/config/application.rb:18:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized
>   constant Bundler (NameError) rails_1      |  from
>   /app/config/environment.rb:2:in`require_relative' rails_1      | 
>   from /app/config/environment.rb:2:in `<top (required)>' rails_1      |
>   from config.ru:3:in`require_relative' rails_1      |  from
>   config.ru:3:in `block in <main>' rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`
>   instance_eval' rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in
>   `initialize' rails_1      |  from config.ru:in`new' rails_1      | 
>   from config.ru:in `<main>' rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`eval'
>   rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in
>   `new_from_string' rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/rack-2.0.6/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`
>   parse_file' rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:318:in
>   `load_rackup' rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/configuration.rb:243:in`
>   app' rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/runner.rb:145:in
>   `load_and_bind' rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/single.rb:96:in`run'
>   rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/launcher.rb:184:in `run'
>   rails_1      |  from
>   /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/lib/puma/cli.rb:78:in`run' rails_1
>   |  from /usr/local/bundle/gems/puma-3.12.0/bin/puma:10:in `<top
>   (required)>' rails_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/bin/puma:23:in`
>   load' rails_1      |  from /usr/local/bundle/bin/puma:23:in `'

Here are the errors I was getting initially:

1. At first I was getting an error saying I required bundler 2.0 was required, so I added that to my Dockerfile.
2. Then I was getting this error:
   "Unable to load application: Bundler::GemNotFound: Could not find bootsnap-1.4.0 in any of the sources"
   So I then manually removed the bootsnap gem from the Gemfile, and I commented out the config/boot.rb file.
3. Now I got the error posted above.

Comment: I tried your setup with a new rails 5 application and everything worked fine... I just see something weird in your configuration, `../../railsapp` in your `docker-compose.yml` will build your application from a different folder, is that what you expect?

Comment: Yes that is where my railsapp is.  Wierd I am getting this error ```Unable to load application: Bundler::LockfileError: You must use Bundler 2 or greater with this lockfile.``` locally.